# Converting a bunch of prime numbers into a set

Tags: python, list, numbers, set, prime-factoring

```py
for i in range(2, 100):
  prime = True
  for k in range(2, i):
    if i % k == 0:
      prime = False
      break
  if prime:
      print(i)
```

the Outcome is:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
```

Is it possible for the outcome to be placed in a set or a list?

Comment: Instead of printing `i`, add `i` to a set that you initialize before the loop starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For set do something like this

```py
st = set()
for i in range(2, 100):
  prime = True
  for k in range(2, i):
    if i % k == 0:
      prime = False
      break
  if prime:
      st.add(i)

print(st)
```

For list do something like this

```py
lst = list()
for i in range(2, 100):
  prime = True
  for k in range(2, i):
    if i % k == 0:
      prime = False
      break
  if prime:
      lst.append(i)

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

To record the answer, you need to declare a list outside the `for` loop. For example, let's call it `primes`.

Then, instead of writing `print(i)`, use:

```py
primes.append(i)
```

to add the number `i` to your list.

Here is the full code:

```py
primes = []
for i in range(2, 100):
  prime = True
  for k in range(2, i):
    if i % k == 0:
      prime = False
      break
  if prime:
    primes.append(i)

print(primes)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice one liner I've seen somewhere on this site is

```py
[p for p in range(2, 100) if all (p%i!=0 for i in range(2, p))]
```

You can speed this up considerably for larger lists with several optimizations, e.g. using the ceiling(sqrt(p)) for the upper range limit of the `i` loop.

For a set, simply make it

```py
{p for p in range(2, 100) if all (p%i!=0 for i in range(2, p))}
```